# Concat inside Aggregate giving error message

Tags: t-sql

I am doing a query where I am using row numbers from inside a partition and I wanted to use CONCAT to combine several fields to construct a Full name.  When I just add the fields together with a + it's All Good. When I try and use the CONCAT function - I get an error message.  I don't quite understand why - Can someone please tell me whether it is not allowed inside an aggregate?

Here is the code that works fine:

```
USE [AdventureWorks2012]
SELECT 
    count([BusinessEntityID])as NumPeople
    ,[PersonType]
    ,max(case when rnum = 1 then [BusinessEntityID] end) as '1st ID'
    ,max(case when rnum = 2 then [BusinessEntityID] end) as '2nd ID'
    ,max(case when rnum = 1 then [FirstName]+' '+[LastName] end ) as '1st FullName'
    ,max(case when rnum = 2 then [FirstName]+' '+[LastName] end ) as '2nd FullName'

from 
    (   
        Select *, row_number() over (partition by [PersonType]  order by [BusinessEntityID]) as rnum
        FROM
        [Person].[Person] 
    ) x
group by [PersonType]
```

and it's output:

```
+-----------+------------+--------+--------+----------------+------------------+
| NumPeople | PersonType | 1st ID | 2nd ID | 1st FullName   | 2nd FullName     |
+-----------+------------+--------+--------+----------------+------------------+
| 273       | EM         | 1      | 2      | Ken Sánchez    | Terri Duffy      |
| 289       | GC         | 2091   | 2092   | David Ortiz    | Qiang Wang       |
| 18484     | IN         | 1699   | 1700   | David Robinett | Rebecca Robinson |
| 753       | SC         | 291    | 293    | Gustavo Achong | Catherine Abel   |
| 17        | SP         | 274    | 275    | Stephen Jiang  | Michael Blythe   |
| 156       | VC         | 1491   | 1493   | Paula Moberly  | Suchitra Mohan   |
+-----------+------------+--------+--------+----------------+------------------+
```

This is the code that gives an error:

```
USE [AdventureWorks2012]
SELECT 
    count([BusinessEntityID])as NumPeople
    ,[PersonType]
    ,max(case when rnum = 1 then [BusinessEntityID] end) as '1st ID'
    ,max(case when rnum = 2 then [BusinessEntityID] end) as '2nd ID'
    ,max(case when rnum = 1 then (concat(p.[FirstName], stuff(p.[MiddleName],1,0,' '), stuff(p.[LastName],1,0,' ') end ) as '1st FullName'
    ,max(case when rnum = 2 then (concat(p.[FirstName], stuff(p.[MiddleName],1,0,' '), stuff(p.[LastName],1,0,' ')end ) as '2nd FullName'
from 
    (   
        Select *, row_number() over (partition by [PersonType]  order by [BusinessEntityID]) as rnum
        FROM
        [Person].[Person] 
    ) x
group by [PersonType]
```

And here is the error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'end'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near 'x'.
```

I am sure this is simply something that Microsoft SQL Server does not allow - but I'd like to know what it is that can't be done - so that I can be sure to avoid that when I need to.  OR if there is some way to do this then that'd be great too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe parenthesis is the only issue here. The two lines where `concat` is used go like this `...) end) as '...`, when they should read like this `...))) end) as '...`. Full query is below.

```
USE [AdventureWorks2012]
SELECT 
    count([BusinessEntityID])as NumPeople
    ,[PersonType]
    ,max(case when rnum = 1 then [BusinessEntityID] end) as '1st ID'
    ,max(case when rnum = 2 then [BusinessEntityID] end) as '2nd ID'
    ,max(case when rnum = 1 then (concat(p.[FirstName], stuff(p.[MiddleName],1,0,' '), stuff(p.[LastName],1,0,' '))) end)  as '1st FullName'
    ,max(case when rnum = 2 then (concat(p.[FirstName], stuff(p.[MiddleName],1,0,' '), stuff(p.[LastName],1,0,' '))) end) as '2nd FullName'
from 
    (   
        Select *, row_number() over (partition by [PersonType]  order by [BusinessEntityID]) as rnum
        FROM
        [Person].[Person] 
    ) x
group by [PersonType]
```

Comment: THANK YOU!    This did the trick.  I feel pretty stupid about making such a simple mistake.   But I suppose if you're not making mistakes you're not learning...